# Conversation between the Krishna and Karna

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas, karna, kurukshetra

Krishna had given many offers to Karna for coming to Pandava's side. Like...

If Karna would come into the Pandava's side then Krishna would make him king of Hastinapura after winning the battle of Kurukshetra?

What is the summary of that conversations between the Krishna and Karna when Krishna at the before Kurukshetra battle started?

Comment: Full conversation would be very lengthy. It took one or two whole chapters. I am afraid there will be a copy paste answer would be pasted (which are discouraged). You may ask for a summary.

Comment: You can watch the conversation here <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LcjObx3eWE>. Language is hindi but the video has english subtitles.
This is a sequence from the famous Mahabharat Tv Series .